# Why should I use SQL compared to regular Java data structures?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am getting started working on a Java project I inherited from my predecessor. I am new to SQL, but SQLite is used to store various different types of data in this system. Previously, I always would store this type of information in internal Java data structures (i.e. Hashmap of usernames, etc.)

My question is why is SQL considered a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

SQL solves a number of problems that are not addressed by native programming languages.  These may not be important for a particular application.  But, here are some examples.

SQL can process data both from disk and in memory, transparently.  It has the notion of a table, which is persistent and stored on disk, but the processing can all be in memory (if the table is already loaded into the page cache).

SQL seemlessly handles data as it gets larger, managing both memory and disk.

SQL handles security and authorization.  New methods do not have to be invented.

SQL ensures atomicity of transactions, so you don't have to worry about partial updates to the system in the event of a failure.

SQL seemlessly enables multiple clients to access the same data, with the database taking care of concurrency issues.

SQL can readily handle multiple different types of entities and the processing needed to combine them.

Although not applicable to SQLite, SQL often takes advantage of multiple processors and multiple disks -- transparently to the application.

However, I must emphasize, this doesn't mean that all data in all applications should be stored in a database (although I do lean in that direction).  You may have an application where an external data store simply isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

An external database such as SQLite provides persistence and allows you to share data among multiple instances of your application.

Comment: This is the big one I didnt even think about. I definitely have to use this due to the existence of multiple instances of my app. Thanks!